# You should use a persistent object cache. Why does Memcached on Wordpress not work on a LAMP stack with multiple virtual hosts?

Tags: memcached

I have a LAMP stack with multiple virtual hosts. Memcached is not working in Wordpress, It used to untill I created more virtual hosts.

From WordPress I get:

```
You should use a persistent object cache
```

From W3 Total Cache, I get the following:

```
The following memcached servers are not responding or not running:

Database Cache: 127.0.0.1:11211.
Object Cache: 127.0.0.1:11211.

This message will automatically disappear once the issue is resolved.
```

My info.php [here](https://ibb.co/qrk37Gt)

lsof -i :11211

```
COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
memcached 350432 memcache 22u IPv4 5140918 0t0 TCP localhost:11211 (LISTEN)
memcached 350432 memcache 23u IPv6 5140919 0t0 TCP ip6-localhost:11211 (LISTEN)

In /etc/memcached.conf I have set -l 127.0.0.1 and also l ::1 for ipv6.
```

-vv

```
Dec 23 20:24:46 a-c-d systemd-memcached-wrapper[369407]: authenticated() in cmd 0x01 is false
Dec 23 20:24:46 a-c-d systemd-memcached-wrapper[369407]: >24 Writing an error: Auth failure.
Dec 23 20:24:46 a-c-d systemd-memcached-wrapper[369407]: >24 Writing bin
```

var//log/apache2/error.log:

```
PHP message: [ERROR] WP_CACHE constant is not present in wp-config.php 

PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/Util_Installed.php on line 145', referer: https://www.example.com/wp-adminplugin_status=all&paged=1&s
/plugins.php?
```

EDIT:

I can see [here](https://ibb.co/cNgM44N) redis is enabled even though I have deleted it completely, this is weird.

Any help on how to resolve this would be really great, thanks!

I have tried everything I can think of. Logging as much as possible, researching the web. I exspect to get memcached to work again :)

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative just want to using  persistent object caching, you may try Docket Cache https://wordpress.org/plugins/docket-cache/